# Ruby on Rails 3 convert time to DateTime in specific timezone

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have column which stores only time. I want to convert to it into datetime and then to a specific timezone. When I do it on console using only the attribute, it shows correct conversion value. But when I use it in query the query shows the current time in UTC. Suppose I have time "05:15" stored in Central time. Now when I want to fetch records for a interval of 30 minutes plus and minus of this time, I do following,

```
day  = Time.now
# departure_time_from _db below is the name of column in table which store time
departure = departure_time_from _db.change(:day => date.day, :month => date.month, :year => date.year)
departure = departure.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
```

When I execute above code on console and see the value, it shows correct converted value. But when I use this variable in below query, current time gets used instead of the departure time.

```
Model.where("column_name > ? and "column_name < ?, departure - 30.minutes, departure + 30.minutes)
```

The time used in above query should be the time I want i.e Central time zone, but in query output, it shows UTC being used.

Please let me know what i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter what time zone the query uses in the `where` clause as long as it's the same time representation. The time you're seeing in your query output from Rails is most likely the UTC equivalent of the ruby `DateTime` object being passed to the `where` statement. So if `departure` is 12:00 noon (UTC -6) in your Ruby code then the time shown in the SQL query will be 18:00, which corresponds to noon CST.

Comment: Do you mean to say that whatever Datetime I provide, the Datetime in the query will be as per UTC, i.e. If I provide a DateTime in CST, while execution, it will be converted to UTC.